# 404 error for 1 Slim route on GoDaddy while it works perfectly on localhost

Tags: php, apache, slim

I have a multiple GET, POST and PUT routes declared in my **Slim v2** App and the API had been working perfectly until today. Out of 2 POST routes, the first one declared is returning a **404 Not Found** error. This only happens when I call the API on my GoDaddy hosting; when I test it on my localhost it works fine. This is so weird I have ran out of ideas on how to debug this problem. I am using Postman to execute and test the calls to both of servers, local and GoDaddy. Also, the calls to the GoDaddy hosted API are done via HTTPS. My *.htaccess* file on both servers looks like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L,QSA]
RewriteRule .* - [env=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
```

- Pastebin to [curl calls](http://pastebin.com/Y6XPjd2W)
- Screenshot of [Postman call](https://imgur.com/a/zMnzX)
- Pastebin to [code fragment](http://pastebin.com/aPXPkhhR)

Comment: How do the two POST routes look? Also show example curl requests including the headers: $ curl --include http://example.com/api/foo

Comment: @MikaTuupola does this [Pastebin](http://pastebin.com/Y6XPjd2W) help? After performing a couple GET/POST request on my API I'm now more confused about what's actually going on.

Comment: @MikaTuupola this is what I get [via Postman](http://imgur.com/a/zMnzX)

Comment: @MikaTuupola This is a fragment of [my code](http://pastebin.com/aPXPkhhR); routes included.

Comment: You are supposed to add the information to your question, not into comments.

Comment: @MikaTuupola done

Answer (score 0):

When doing a `POST` request to `/apifolder/v1/addcheckin` server responds with 301 redirect to which causes the client to make a `GET` request to `/apifolder/v1/addcheckin`. Since there is no such GET route defined server responds with 404 error.

```
$ curl -i -X POST https://myurl.com/apifolder/v1/addcheckin
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Date: Sun, 26 Feb 2017 02:26:34 GMT
Location: https://myurl.com/apifolder/v1/addcheckin
```

Check the middleware and the rest of the code to see what causes the 301 redirect.

Comment: Thanks for taking time to help me out on this. I'm researching "error 301 on a Slim 2 POST route". But does the fact that it happens only with the `addcheckin` route means the problem should be on the code for that specific route?